# Token based access to docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

We have a contractor who is going to work remotely but we do not want our source code on his machine. We have decided not to use any Desktop as a service. My thought was we could provide a docker image to that person and grant him access based on access token which we can get from AWS. Once that person's contract is terminated, we disable all access to it. I wanted to know if this is possible? Can I configure my code repository to allow access only if he does it from the docker container? 
My knowledge of docker is currently limited so please excuse me if this sounds silly.

Comment: This is not how docker containers are meant to be run. Docker really one wants to run a single process and then exit when its done. One of the large common mistakes that people make is the thing that a docker container is a full on VM. its is not. IT does not do things like run upstart, so common services that you expect to run on a VM are not going to be running on a container.

If you dont want a managed virtual desktop app. You would be better off running an EC2 instance with a gui installed and having the person RDP into it.